# How can use Boto3 to find and delete an RDS snapshot based on it's name?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-rds

I am trying to create a Lambda function to delete old RDS snapshots. However, it appears that wildcards aren't a supported feature for Boto3 describe_db_snapshots. I have a function that creates a weekly RDS snapshot with a name that has date and time (weekly-2021-05-05-15-19). However, I want to create a Lambda function that deletes the old snapshot after a week, before a new one is created with a similar name. The code I have working prints out all the DBSnapshotIdentifier's for a specific database but I only want it to print out the DBSnapshotIdentifier if it's similar to "weekly-*". Once I get the print working, I'll edit it to delete the snapshot. Right now, the code returns nothing. I want it to return only the snapshot that starts with "weekly-".

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('rds')
DB = 'mytestdatabase'

#-----Define Lambda function-----#
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=DB,
        SnapshotType='manual'
        )

    for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
        if (i['DBSnapshotIdentifier']) == 'weekly-*':
        print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
```

Comment: You want to match and print any snapshot that starts with this "weekly-" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function inside your Lambda function to check the name of snapshot that starts with "weekly-" like this:

```
def snap_check(text):
    result = text.startswith('weekly-')
    return result

text = "weekly-2021-05-05-15-19"
print(snap_check(text))
```

Output:

```
True
```

**True**  - Means your snapshot startswith "weekly-"

**False** - Means your snapshot doesn't starts with "weekly-"

Your code will look something like this:

```
import boto3


def snap_check(text):
    result = text.startswith('weekly-')
    return result


client = boto3.client('rds')
DB = 'mytestdatabase'

#-----Define Lambda function-----#
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    snapshots = client.describe_db_snapshots(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=DB,
        SnapshotType='manual'
        )

    for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
        if snap_check(str(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])):
            print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
```

Comment: @cdh12 Glad to help you.

Comment: show empty if i run the above code... anything we need to change... i added DB name

Answer (score 0):

I used the similar function and it prints out all the required snapshots, however i would now need to put a delete logic in there so that it deletes all snapshots prior to 1 week. As we only want to keep 7 days of snapshots